# Could not find a declaration file for module 'vuex' with create-vue

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vuex, eslint

I am trying to initalize a project with Vue3 and typescript, but after adding vuex to the project, it won´t compile.

What I did:

1. First I created the project with create-vue, using the recommend options:

[Creating Vue Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TX0fL.png)

2. Installed vuex:

```bash
npm install vuex@next --save
```

3. Followed the steps in Vuex Docs: [Typescript support](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/typescript-support.html#typing-store-property-in-vue-component)

So, in my simple store file I have:

```
import { type InjectionKey } from 'vue'
import { createStore, Store } from 'vuex'

// define your typings for the store state
export interface State {
  count: number
}

// define injection key
export const key: InjectionKey<Store<State>> = Symbol()

export const store = createStore<State>({
  state: {
    count: 0
  }
})
```

But if I run `npm run build`, this is the result:

```
src/stores/index.ts:2:36 - error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'vuex'. '/home/user/projects/vue_projects/init-test/node_modules/vuex/dist/vuex.mjs' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  There are types at '/home/user/projects/vue_projects/init-test/node_modules/vuex/types/index.d.ts', but this result could not be resolved when respecting package.json "exports". The 'vuex' library may need to update its package.json or typings.

2 import { createStore, Store } from 'vuex'
```

It seems that it has found vuex types, but could not import anyway. How do I solve that?

I already added a `vuex.d.ts`, following the vuex docs.

```
import { Store } from 'vuex'

declare module '@vue/runtime-core' {
  // declare your own store states
  interface State {
    count: number
  }

  // provide typings for `this.$store`
  interface ComponentCustomProperties {
    $store: Store<State>
  }
}
```

Comment: Same issue for me :-) It is probably something simple but so far I could not figure it out.

Comment: Well, reading would have helped ;-) On the top of the vuex docs it says that pinia is now the new default. So I am switching to that and so far it seems to work. Of course that does not help with the issue at hand but maybe it is an option for you as well

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It appears to be caused by a change in a relatively new version of typescript that no longer recognizes vuex type definitions.

## Workaround 1

Save the following code under an appropriate directory with a name like `vuex.d.ts`. This should allow TypeScript to correctly recognize the vuex module.

```
declare module "vuex" {
  export * from "vuex/types/index.d.ts";
  export * from "vuex/types/helpers.d.ts";
  export * from "vuex/types/logger.d.ts";
  export * from "vuex/types/vue.d.ts";
}
```

## Workaround 2

I have not confirmed this, but using a slightly older version of typescript may solve the problem.

Comment: package.json should be updated:   "exports": {
    ".": {
      "module": "./dist/vuex.esm-bundler.js",
      "require": "./dist/vuex.cjs.js",
      "import": "./dist/vuex.mjs"
    }, must have "types" field

Comment: Workaround 1 works for me. Thanks